# Creating only a single standalone executable from .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Let's say I have an application with a `.py` file extension and I want to use PyInstaller to create it into a standalone executable with a `.exe` file extension. However I only want *one* `.exe` file that does not require dists nor a workpath.

Is it possible to use PyInstaller to create a standalone file that does *not* need a distpath nor workpath to function correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the --onefile option is what you are looking for?  This has worked fine for me in the past in order to create a single .exe file.